# Add Iframe in knockout js template

Tags: knockoutjs, magento2.3.2, checkout-page, credit-card, iframe

I am working on custom payment method with SnapPay integration.
I want to add iframe in `vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cc-form.html`

```
<iframe id="tokenFrame" width="100%" height="40" name="tokenFrame" src="https://stage.snappayglobal.com/Interop/InteropCCAjaxTokenizer/Index/<?=$return['requestid'] ?>"  frameborder="0" scrolling="no">.</iframe>
```

where `$return['requestid']` dyanamic variable.

I don't know how can achive that.

How can I use this file `vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/templates/form/cc.phtml` as a template file.? Is this possible?

Anyone suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This will be your phtml.

```
<div data-bind='component: "snapPay-integration"'></div>
```

This will be your js binding.

```
var requestid = 234234;
ko.components.register('snapPay-integration', {       
    template: '<iframe id="tokenFrame" width="100%" height="40" name="tokenFrame" src="https://stage.snappayglobal.com/Interop/InteropCCAjaxTokenizer/Index/' + requestid +  '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">.</iframe>'
});

ko.applyBindings();
```

Hope this might work for you.